PWA ask users to force update
Background : I had created an android app in flutter and released it in the playstore, and then I updated the app to a PWA app and it's been over a year, but when I was checking app statistics I was seeing there are quite a lot of users still using the Flutter app
Is there a way to nudge them to force update to the PWA?
